# Output point coordinates a complex number

Tags: complex

How output point through ListPlot coordinates Z complex number using Re [ ], Im [ ].

```
a0=1+1 I;
a1=RecurrenceTable[{
z[n+1]==z[n]+a0,
z[0]==0},
{z},
{n,1,5}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `real` and `imaginary` parts of `a1`

```
realParts = Re @@@ a1;
imaginaryParts = Im @@@ a1;
```

Assuming, you want to plot `imaginary part` against `real part`,

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{realParts, imaginaryParts}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: or `ListPlot[ReIm[a1]\[Transpose]]`  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html